# ¿En qué contextos son intercambiables las voces "complemento" y "suplemento"?

Tags: sustantivos, sinónimos

Aunque las voces *complemento* y *suplemento* comparten una acepción, en muchos casos cada una tiene sus propios ámbitos de uso. Así, un bolso es un complemento a la ropa, pero con el periódico te pueden incluir un suplemento de moda.

La acepción común es:

> **[complemento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A1KrS6q)**
>
> 1. m. Cosa, cualidad o circunstancia que se añade a otra para hacerla íntegra o perfecta.
>
> **[suplemento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YlgimFZ)**
>
> 2. m. Cosa o accidente que se añade a otra cosa para hacerla íntegra o perfecta.

¿En qué contextos son estas voces intercambiables? Se me ocurre que aunque en español se suele usar *complemento alimenticio*, en portugués se usa *suplemento alimentar*, y la verdad es que hablar de *suplemento alimenticio* no me suena raro. ¿Hay otros contextos además de este en los que las voces sean completamente sinónimas? ¿O consideráis que, aunque se parezcan, las definiciones no son exactamente iguales?

Comment: Interesante pregunta.  Yo pienso que un documento se podría describir como *complemento* o bien *suplemento*, aunque para algunos documentos sería un poquito más apto el uno o el otro.  Pero por ejemplo si tenemos un conjunto musical que está más o menos bien, pero que queda súper bien con cierto instrumento adicional, entonces ese instrumento agregado sería el complemento perfecto, pero no el suplemento perfecto.  Entonces, pues sí, muy bien la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Pese a las definiciones oficiales, tengo la sensación de que un complemento se percibe como una cosa que se añade a algo en circunstancias en que **el conjunto pasa a ser parte de un todo mayor**, mientras que un suplemento es un añadido que **no forma una nueva entidad**. En parte por esto, la palabra "suplemento" puede tender a percibirse como peyorativa más que "complemento": un complemento "redondea" una entidad, mientras que un suplemento se le agrega a ésta.

Por ejemplo, una voz de un timbre determinado puede ser "el complemento perfecto para" otra voz de un timbre diferente; ambas pasan a formar un todo mayor, un dúo de voces; si hablásemos de un suplemento, en cambio, podría percibirse que a la primera voz le falta algo. La asociación fonética entre "complemento" y "completo" por un lado, y entre "suplemento" y "suplir" por el otro, ayuda también.

Para responder la pregunta, entonces, hay que apuntar a los casos donde se pueden ignorar estas diferentes connotaciones, que no sé si serán muchos. Quizá estemos demasiado influidos por el lenguaje publicitario. Al menos para mí, y retomando los ejemplos de OP, "complemento alimenticio" suena muy bien para venderle un producto orientado a gente sana que quiere alimentarse bien, mientras que "suplemento alimenticio" suena como si estuviese destinado a personas con nutrición deficiente.